# How to catch exception from powershell script file in the C#?

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0

How to catch the exception which are thrown in Powershell script files in C# file?
We basically call powershlell script file from c# after configuring runspace.Powershell script files exceptions are caught in those files itself.But we dont know how to probagate it to C#.